# How do I recursively replace (i.e. upgrade) a set of files in SVN?

Tags: svn, frameworks, replace

We use a third party framework which we store in our repository (yes, this might not be the best way, but it allows us to deploy easily). Recently, we found that we needed some functionality from the latest version of the framework.

**Is there a way to tell SVN to just do a deep replace of the directory without having to do an `svn delete PHPExcel/` and then do an `svn add PHPExcel/`?**

If this is the easiest way, no worries, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that since the thing you are depending on is an artifact that is pre-built, it is considered an 'artifact', which shouldn't belong to a source control repository. The whole point of source control is to control 'source' files, and not 'binary' files. I would probably use a build tool like rake to put the correct binaries in its place.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address my question at all. I'm not interested in philosophical,big-picture discussions. I am interested in knowing if there is "...a way to tell SVN to just do a deep replace of the directory without having to do an svn delete PHPExcel/ and then do an svn add PHPExcel/?"